# Allocate char array and strings

Tags: c, arrays, character, c-strings, strlen

I have problem understanding the code below.

1. What value `index=strlen(strs[0])` gets?
2. `char *a= malloc (sizeof(char)*(index+1))` Is this the standard way to allocate array for char array?
3. What does `strs[i][j]` represent?

This is the code I found on leetcode. Just trying to understand the code. (code from sanghi user on leetcode)

```
#include<string.h>
char* longestCommonPrefix(char** strs, int strsSize) 
{
    int i=0; int j=0;int index;int tempindex=0;
    if(strsSize<1)
    return "";
    index=strlen(strs[0]);
    char *a;
    a= malloc(sizeof(char)*(index+1));
    strcpy(a,strs[0]);
    for(i=1;i<strsSize;i++)
    {   tempindex=0;
        for(j=0;j<index;j++)
        { 
            if(a[j]==strs[i][j])
            tempindex++;
            else
            {a[j]='\0';
             break;
            }
        } 
          if (tempindex==0)return ("");
          if(tempindex<index)index=tempindex;

    }
    return a;

}
```

Expected results can be found on https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/

Comment: Run it in a debugger and examine the values you're interested in.

Comment: It seems to me like you need to invest time and money into some books to read. Learning from online judge/competition sites is not something I would recommend (I would quite strongly recommend just about anything else than such sites)..

Answer (score 0):

`strs` is an array of strings. `strsSize` is the number of strings in the array.

```
index = strlen(strs[0]);
```

This simply gets the length of `strs[0]`, the first string in the array.

```
a = malloc(sizeof(char)*index+1);
```

This will allocate enough memory to store a string of the same size. I say enough memory because each string actually has length + 1 characters. The last character is `\0`, a null terminator. You always have to make sure to terminate your strings or else a bunch of weird buffer overflow stuff can happen.

```
str[i][j]
```

This accesses the jth character in the ith string in the array.

Comment: "*strs is an array of strings*" No, it's a pointer to a pointer to `char`, a `char**`. Pointers are not arrays, nor 1D, nor 2D, nor .... You are simplifying too much.

Answer (score -1):

For starters the program is bad and invalid.:)

For example the size of the one dimensional array first element of which is pointed to by the parameter `strs` shall have the type `size_t` instead of `int`.

And all other variables that deal with indices also shall have the type `size_t` as for example

```
size_t index = strlen( strs[0] );
```

because the standard C function `strlen` has the return type `size_t`.

The source array is not changed in the function so the first parameter shall be declared with the qualifier `const`.

That is the function declaration shall look like

```
char * longestCommonPrefix( const char** strs, size_t strsSize);
```

Farther the elements (strings) of the array can have different lengths, So this loop

```
for(j=0;j<index;j++)
```

has undefined behavior because some element (string) of the array can have length less than the value of the variable `index`.

In fact there is no need to calculate lengths of the elements of the array. The loop can use the condition

```
for( j=0; j < index && strs[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
```

And moreover the function has a memory leak due to this return sub-statement in the if statement

```
a= malloc(sizeof(char)*(index+1));
//...
if (tempindex==0)return ("");
```

That is the allocated memory pointed to by the pointer `a` will not released.

> What value index=strlen(strs[0]) gets?

`index` gets the length of the string stored in the first element of the array of strings.

For example if you have an array

```
char *strs[] = { "Hello", "Bye", "Good Morning" };
```

then `index` is set to the length of the string `"Hello"`.

> char *a= malloc (sizeof(char)*(index+1)) Is this the standard way to
>   allocate array for char array?

Yes in this declaration there is allocated a memory large enough to store the string (including its terminating zero) of the first element of the array pointed to by `strs`.

> What does strs[i][j] represent?

`strs[i][j]` access j-th character of the i-th element of the array pointed to by `strs`.

For example for the declaration above `strs[0][0]` is equal to `'H`', `strs[0][1]` is equal to `'e'`, `strs[1][0]` is equal to `'B'` and so on.

P.S. A better approach to define the function is the following as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t longestCommonPrefix( const char **strs, size_t strsSize )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    if ( strsSize != 0 )
    {
        n = strlen( *strs );

        for ( size_t i = 1; n != 0 && i < strsSize; i++ )
        {
            size_t j = 0;

            while ( j < n && strs[i][j] == strs[i-1][j] ) j++;

            if ( j < n ) n = j;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char * strs[] = { "0123456789", "012345", "0123" };

    size_t n = longestCommonPrefix( ( const char ** )strs, sizeof( strs ) / sizeof( *strs ) );

    char *p = NULL;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        p = malloc( n + 1 );
        memcpy( p, strs[0], n );
        p[n] = '\0';

        printf( "The longest common prefix is \"%s\"\n", p );
    }

    free( p );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The longest common prefix is "0123"
```